Pass variable value after state change to another class in flutter/dart
I want to get the value of a radio button group which is stored in a variable called currentOption in my Home class,  i want to pass the value to my Database class . My issue is when I pass currentOption variable to my Database class and print it in the database class the value always stays the same as the initial value it has in the Home class even after I toggle the the radio button to trigger the value change, but when i print it in the Home class the value of currentOption changes to the value of the radio button I toggled.
Home.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:watch_hub/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:watch_hub/services/database.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:watch_hub/screens/home/watch_list.dart';
import 'package:watch_hub/models/watch.dart';

List<dynamic> options = [0, 'Rolex', 'Longines'];

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({super.key});
  dynamic currentOption = options[0]; //THIS IS THE VARIABLE I WANT TO PASS TO ANOTHER CLASS
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<Watch>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().watches,
      initialData: const [],
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[50],
        drawer: Drawer(
          elevation: 20.0,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                accountName: Text("Flutter"),
                accountEmail: null,
              ),
                //VALUE OF currentOption CHANGES WHEN I TOGGLE EITHER OF THESE CHECKBOXES
              ListTile(
                title: const Text('None'),
                leading: Radio<dynamic>(
                  value: options[0],
                  groupValue: widget.currentOption,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      widget.currentOption = value;
                      print("current is ${widget.currentOption}");
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                height: 0.1,
              ),
              ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Rolex'),
                  leading: Radio(
                    value: options[1],
                    groupValue: widget.currentOption,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        widget.currentOption = value;
                        print("current is ${widget.currentOption}");
                      });
                    },
                  )),
              ListTile(
                  title: const Text('Longines'),
                  leading: Radio(
                    value: options[2],
                    groupValue: widget.currentOption,
                    onChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        widget.currentOption = value;
                        print("current is ${widget.currentOption}");
                      });
                    },
                  )),
              ListTile(
                title: Text("Promotions"),
                leading: Icon(Icons.local_offer),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Watch Hub"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.brown[400],
          elevation: 0.0,
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: Text("Logout"),
              onPressed: () async {
                await _auth.signOut();
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: const WatchList(),
      ),
    );

  }
}

database.dart
import "package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart";
import "package:watch_hub/models/watch.dart";
import 'package:watch_hub/screens/home/home.dart';

class DatabaseService {
  final String? uid;
  DatabaseService({this.uid});
  //collection reference
  final CollectionReference users =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users");

  final CollectionReference watch_list =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("watch_hub");
  dynamic brand = "Longines";
  dynamic model = "Aviation Big Eye";
  

  Future setUserData(
      String email, String address, String fullName, String phone) async {
    return await users.doc(uid).set({
      "email": email,
      "address": address,
      "fullName": fullName,
      "phone": phone,
    });
  }

  //watch list from snapshot
  List<Watch> _watchListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    print("without $option");
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) {
      return Watch(
        id: doc['id'] ?? '',
        brand: doc['brand'] ?? '',
        model: doc['model'] ?? '',
        type: doc['type'] ?? '',
        popularity: doc['popularity'] ?? 0,
        price: doc['price'].toString(),
        image: doc['image'] ?? '',
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  //get watches list

  Stream<List<Watch>> get watches {
dynamic option = Home().currentOption;
/* WHEN I PRINT THIS THE VALUE OS option IS ALWAYS 0 BECAUSE THAT WAS ITS INITIAL VALUE IN home.dart */
    print("option is $option"); 
    late Query filter;

    option is String
        ? filter = watch_list.where("brand", isEqualTo: option)
        : filter = watch_list.where("brand", isNotEqualTo: true);


    print(watch_list);
    return filter.snapshots().map(_watchListFromSnapshot);
  }
}



When you use:
dynamic option = Home().currentOption;

That means you are creating another instance of Home class. So, the currentOption value will always be default (0);
Here's the solution:

Create a class and declare static variables and access and update from anywhere.

class OptionsClass{
   static List<dynamic> options = [0, 'Rolex', 'Longines'];
   static dynamic currentOption = options[0];
}

Update the current option like this..
 ListTile(
          title: const Text('Rolex'),
          leading: Radio(
          value: OptionsClass.options[1], // 0, //2
          groupValue: OptionsClass.currentOption,
          onChanged: (value) {
             setState(() {
                OptionsClass.currentOption = value;
                print("current is ${OptionsClass.currentOption}");
                  });
                },
          )),

Use the currentOption variable anywhere.
Stream<List<Watch>> get watches {
dynamic option = OptionsClass.currentOption;
...
}

Easy solution:

Just make your "currentOption" variable "static"

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

   static dynamic currentOption = options[0];
...
}

Update it like:
HomePage.currentOption = "value";

and use it like:
final currentOption = HomePage.currentOption;

